# Open Graph Linter Errors

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to debug why images are not showing on the right panel Facebook share box.  I have tried to debug using the og linter, but can't get it right.

URL example is here http://pluba.com/Classified/DisplayAd.asp?id=24096

On the right hand side in the facebook box you can see just text posted, but no image.  The image shows up fine on a facebook newsfeed otherwise.

Linter debug:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpluba.com%2FClassified%2FDisplayAd.asp%3Fid%3D24096

I'm thinking i've got something screwy in my og tags.  Here are two of the reported errors

Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Any help would be appreciated.  I tried to research on openstack, but still can't figure it out. thanks.  vic

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have looks right. I don't think the like box shows an image next to the post attachments since we don't have much room.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the response. I had tried to open the spacing earlier but it wasn't an issue related to width or height.